# c++ error: invalid use of member 'calls_object::OBJECT' in static member function

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, function, static

I got the following error from the code below.

`error: invalid use of member 'calls_object::OBJECT' in static member function|`
`error: from this location`

from the line `OBJECT->call();` line 29.

Basically the function must be static because its really a simplified version of the code 
which creates a windows thread. I just can't seem to use pointers within a static function but I can create the object within the static function no problem. Is there another way?

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)windowsthread, (LPVOID)i, NULL, &m_id);

static DWORD_PTR WINAPI windowsthread()
{
    OBJECT->call();
}
```

l

```
class object
{
        private:

        public:

        object(){}
        ~object(){}
        void call(){}
};
class calls_object
{
    private:

        object* OBJECT;

    public:

    calls_object()
    {
        OBJECT = new object();
    }
    ~calls_object(){}

    #ifdef _WIN32
    static void windows_function()
    {
        OBJECT->call();
    }
    #endif
};
int main()
{
    calls_object O;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

```
static void windows_function()
{
    OBJECT->call();
}
```

Is declared as `static`. It means it does not receive an implicit `this` pointers: in other words, it does not operate on an *instance* of `calls_object`. Therefore, it cannot see the `OBJECT` member variable.

Either declare the function as non-static, or declare `OBJECT` as a `static` member variable (whatever makes more sense in your application).

> Basically the function must be static because its really a simplified version of the code which creates a windows thread

Since you are (unfortunately) dealing with a function (`CreateThread`) that accepts a function pointer, you cannot even use `std::bind`. However, `CreateThread` lets you provide a function which accepts a pointer (to `void`, see the prototype of [`ThreadProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Just pass a pointer to an `object` as the fourth argument to `CreateThread`, and let `windowsFunction(void*)` receive that pointer. Inside `windowsFunction()`, which would still be `static` or global (in fact, you do not need the `calls_object` class at all), you can cast that pointer to a pointer to `object` and invoke `call()` on it.

---

Also notice, that your class `calls_object` is leaking memory, since you are forgetting to `delete` the pointer you created in `calls_object`'s constructor:

```
~calls_object() 
{ 
    delete object; // DON'T FORGET THIS!
}
```

Comment: `OBJECT as a static` I'm not sure how to go about that. Can you give an example?

Comment: @lost_with_coding: Honestly, I think you do not want this whole class `calls_object`.

Comment: Of course not this is just a quick example I made up. I usually just use capital letters to show minimal examples of whats wrong.

Comment: "Just pass a pointer to an object as the fourth argument to CreateThread, and let windowsFunction(void*) receive that pointer." What about the parameter `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadMain`. The reference page you sent me said it can crash 64-bit windows so I definitely want that gone. Do I just leave it blank? Could you post what the `CreateThread` function should look like with the object pointer getting passed? And what happens to the function `static  DWORD_PTR WINAPI threadMain()`?

Answer (score 1):

`windows_function` is a static member function, so is not associated with any `calls_object` object. `OBJECT` is a non-`static` data member, so is associated with a `calls_object` object. You cannot access a non-`static` data member from a data member.

Simply make the function non-`static` and it will work.

Think of it this way. If you didn't even create an object of type `calls_object` and your `main` function was just:

```
int main()
{
  calls_object::windows_function();
}
```

Where would you expect this function to get `OBJECT` from? Since `OBJECT` is a non-`static` member, it only exists as part of a `calls_object` object. A `static` member function cannot simply pull `OBJECT` from nowhere.

Comment: "Simply make the function non-static and it will work." Yes, the program I wrote will work but this `CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)windowsthread, (LPVOID)i, NULL, &m_id);` needs the static windowsthread function for some reason?

Comment: @lost_with_coding Yes, that function must take a `static` function. So either redesign your code to be fully static or you'll have to use `std::bind` to bind the non-`static` `windows_function` to an object before passing it to `CreateThread`.