# CreateThread inside a class error: argument of type 'DWORD (windows_thread::)(void*)' does not match 'DWORD (*)(void*)'?

Tags: c++, windows, createthread

I tried to create a thread inside of a class and I got an error. I'm just wondering if there is way around this or must I use threads within `int main()` only?

```
C:\windows_thread_2\windows_thread_2.cpp||In member function 'void windows_thread::thread()':|
C:\windows_thread_2\windows_thread_2.cpp|24|error: argument of type 'DWORD (windows_thread::)(void*)' does not match 'DWORD (*)(void*)'|
C:\windows_thread_2\windows_thread_2.cpp||In member function 'DWORD windows_thread::Thread_no_1(void*)':|
C:\windows_thread_2\windows_thread_2.cpp|70|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

heres the code.

```
#include <windows.h>
//#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 255

class windows_thread
{
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// A function to Display the message indicating in which tread we are
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
    public:

        windows_thread(){}
        ~windows_thread(){}
        void thread()
        {
            int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;            // Data of Thread 1
            HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;       // variable to hold handle of Thread 1

            HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[1];   // Aray to store thread handles

    // Create thread 1.
            Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0, Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
            if ( Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)  ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);

    // Store Thread handles in Array of Thread Handles as per the requirement of WaitForMultipleObjects()
            Array_Of_Thread_Handles[0] = Handle_Of_Thread_1;


    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
            WaitForMultipleObjects( 1, Array_Of_Thread_Handles, TRUE, INFINITE);

            printf("Since All threads executed lets close their handles \n");

    // Close all thread handles upon completion.
            CloseHandle(Handle_Of_Thread_1);
        }
        void DisplayMessage (HANDLE hScreen, char *ThreadName, int Data, int Count)
        {
            TCHAR msgBuf[BUF_SIZE];
            size_t cchStringSize;
            DWORD dwChars;

    // Print message using thread-safe functions.
    //StringCchPrintf(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, TEXT("Executing iteration %02d of %s having data = %02d \n"), Count, ThreadName, Data);
    //StringCchLength(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, &cchStringSize);
            WriteConsole(hScreen, msgBuf, cchStringSize, &dwChars, NULL);
            Sleep(1000);
        }

//-------------------------------------------
// A function that represents Thread number 1
//-------------------------------------------
        DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
        {
            int     Data = 0;
            int     count = 0;
            HANDLE  hStdout = NULL;

    // Get Handle To screen. Else how will we print?
            if( (hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
                return 1;

    // Cast the parameter to the correct data type passed by callee i.e main() in our case.
            Data = *((int*)lpParam);

            for (count = 0; count <= 4; count++ )
            {
                DisplayMessage (hStdout, "Thread_no_1", Data, count);
            }

            return 0;
        }
};
int main()
{
    windows_thread threading;
    threading.thread();

    return 0;
}
```

I edited the code based on the answer, please edit it if you can solve this error.
`line 78 error: no matching function for call to 'windows_thread::Thread_no_1()'|`

```
#include <windows.h>
//#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 255

class windows_thread
{
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// A function to Display the message indicating in which tread we are
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
    public:

        windows_thread(){}
        ~windows_thread(){}
        void thread()
        {
            int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;            // Data of Thread 1
            HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;       // variable to hold handle of Thread 1

            HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[1];   // Aray to store thread handles

    // Create thread 1.
            Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,  Wrap_Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
            if ( Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)  ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);

    // Store Thread handles in Array of Thread Handles as per the requirement of WaitForMultipleObjects()
            Array_Of_Thread_Handles[0] = Handle_Of_Thread_1;


    // Wait until all threads have terminated.
            WaitForMultipleObjects( 1, Array_Of_Thread_Handles, TRUE, INFINITE);

            printf("Since All threads executed lets close their handles \n");

    // Close all thread handles upon completion.
            CloseHandle(Handle_Of_Thread_1);
        }
        void DisplayMessage (HANDLE hScreen, char *ThreadName, int Data, int Count)
        {
            TCHAR msgBuf[BUF_SIZE];
            size_t cchStringSize;
            DWORD dwChars;

    // Print message using thread-safe functions.
    //StringCchPrintf(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, TEXT("Executing iteration %02d of %s having data = %02d \n"), Count, ThreadName, Data);
    //StringCchLength(msgBuf, BUF_SIZE, &cchStringSize);
            WriteConsole(hScreen, msgBuf, cchStringSize, &dwChars, NULL);
            Sleep(1000);
        }

//-------------------------------------------
// A function that represents Thread number 1
//-------------------------------------------
        DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
        {
            int     Data = 0;
            int     count = 0;
            HANDLE  hStdout = NULL;

    // Get Handle To screen. Else how will we print?
            if( (hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
                return 1;

    // Cast the parameter to the correct data type passed by callee i.e main() in our case.
            Data = *((int*)lpParam);

            for (count = 0; count <= 1; count++ )
            {
                //DisplayMessage (hStdout, "Thread_no_1", Data, count);
            }

            return 0;
        }
        static DWORD WINAPI Wrap_Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
        {
            windows_thread *self = reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(lpParam);
            self->Thread_no_1();
        }
};
int main()
{
    windows_thread threading;
    threading.thread();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread must be a "plain function", not a call to a non-static member function of a class - these require an extra "hidden" argument for the "this-pointer".

Since your code that you have so far doesn't use any member variables [as far as I can see], the easy solution is to make the function `static`.

If you want to use member variables or member functions of your class, then you will need to have a static function and pass the object (`this`) as (part of) the argument to the thread, and then use a `reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(arg);` to convert it back.

Something along these lines:

```
... 
    Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0, Wrap_Thread_no_1, this, 0, NULL);

... 

    static DWORD WINAPI Wrap_Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
    {
          windows_thread *self = reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(lpParam);
          self->Thread_no_1();
    }
```

I have removed your original argument. Assuming the thread is running only one thread per object, you could make it a member variable. If you need multiple threads with individual parameters, then you need to make the passed in parameter a `struct` or `class`, and `reinterpret_cast` to that, and store the `this` pointer as part of that `struct` or `class` [which can then be `windows_thread*` so won't need a cast].

Comment: "pass the object (this) as (part of) the argument to the thread" Which argument though?  `reinterpret_cast<windows_thread*>(arg);` Could you give an example?

Comment: See edit in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks Mats, I think I edited my code correctly otherwise please look at my post and fix it. I got an error on line 78. thanks so far.

Comment: You have a function that takes an argument, I removed the argument... [Although I admit I didn't post that part]

Comment: I guess it was this ` LPVOID lpParam` in `DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )`? I also commented out `Data = *((int*)lpParam);`...

Comment: Yes, that's the part to remove. [Eventually, it sounds like you want to pass another `class` there, but that's for later, I expect]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a [pointer-to-member](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html) to the thread, which is not the same as a raw pointer here.  It requires an object to be attached to it.

```
Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0, Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
```

Make the function `static` by changing this:

```
    DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
```

To this:

```
    static DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam )
```

... which states (correctly) that this function doesn't need `this`.

Comment: The usual approach is to pass an instance of the object as the `LPVOID` argument to a global/static callback.

Comment: @Stephen Lin. Could you post an example of that please?

Comment: @lost_with_coding that wouldn't apply here, since the data you're passing is a local `int`.  See my edit.

Comment: I don't want to use static for the `Thread_no_1` function because I plan on using a pointer from `Thread_no_1` and that too gave me troubles with compiling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186384/c-error-invalid-use-of-member-calls-objectobject-in-static-member-functio

Comment: @lost_with_coding yes, if you want to pass both a pointer to an instance of the object and to another value, you have to put them in some struct together or something...in any case you don't have member variables (yet) on `windows_thread` so passing a pointer to an instance of it won't be that useful.

Comment: @Stephen Lin "in any case you don't have member variables (yet) on windows_thread so passing a pointer to an instance of it won't be that useful" Right the pointer I wanted to pass is an object not of type `windows_thread` and it is created within the constructor of `windows_thread` using a `new` operator.

Comment: @lost_with_coding I don't know what you mean by that...it doesn't look like you're using a `new` operator, `Data_Of_Thread_1` is a local that you're passing the address of...in any case the easiest thing to do right now is to just make the callback `static` and leave everything else the same

Comment: @lost_with_coding see MatsPetersson's answer

Comment: @Stephen Oh no sorry for the misunderstanding I plan on doing that. I guess this is off topic now.